# JLabel click event

Tags: java, swing

If you have two `JLabel`s in a `JFrame` both with the same `MouseListener` click event added to them, how can you tell which `JLabel` was clicked without creating a second actionlistener?

Note: both labels have the same text written on them so that cannot be used to tell them apart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make the two `JLabel`s fields and then check the source of the `MouseEvent`:

```
if (e.getSource() == firstLabel) {
  ...
} else if (e.getSource() == secondLabel) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This will get you a reference to the component ...

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
{
JComponent reference = e.getComponent();
}
```

For a more complete description look at the [Swing Tutorial on MouseListeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: well that gives you the information about the label, and if the two labels have different texts then you could use that to tell them apart, but what if the text is the same?

Comment: @jjj getComponent() or getSource() will return you back a reference to the object that caused the event. With that you should be able to find which it is. by doing if(component1 == getComponent()) ... else ...

Answer (score 0):

take for example, a keyboard. what I did when I created one, is sent over the button to the action listener. I then had the action listener do a myButton.getText(); and I would just type the text onto my screen (a JTextfield in my case). in your main method write:

```
JTextField textfield = new JTextField("", 37);  
JButton myButton = new new JButton("button text here");  
myButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener (textfield, myButton));
```

the full action listener would look like this:

```
//thisMethod is for a keyboard typing into a JTextfield  
import javax.swing.JTextField;  
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;  
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;  
import java.lang.*;    
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {  
JTextField textfield;  
MyActionListener(JTextField textfield, JButton button) {  
    this.textfield = textfield;  
}  
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
        String letter = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printString(textfield.getText()).concat(button.getText());
        textfield.setText (letter);  
    }  
 }
```

this same priciple applies when refering to which button was pressed. you could send over a string, and that string could be used in conditional statements to determine which button was pressed.

Comment: but what if the two labels have the same text?

Comment: send over a string, so instead of:  
JTextField textfield = new JTextField("", 37);
JButton myButton = new new JButton("button text here");
myButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener (textfield, myButton));

you would write: 
JTextField textfield = new JTextField("", 37);
JButton myButton = new new JButton("button text here");
myButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener (textfield, "myButton"));
  then, in the action listener, change the line MyActionListener(JTextField textfield, JButton button) {...}, to MyActionListener(JTextField textfield, String myString) {...}

Comment: then just add a conditionall statement so that it would say :
if (myString.equals("myButton")) { textfield.setText("whatever text you would put in that situation");}

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JLabel which comes from JComponent it has a method called putClientProperty("myValue", myValue). You could put some unique identifier in there upon JLabel creation and retrieve it at event time with getClientProperty("myValue") and then test it.